# How do I get a bot to specify the username and tag of the creator in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

> I am not understanding how to mention the creator of the bot despite changing the tag and username.
> I am using discord.py rewrite.
> Can someone please help me?
> Here is the code:

```
@client.command(aliases=["OWNER", "creator", "CREATOR"])
async def owner(ctx):
```

> I want the code below all that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use youe `User ID` which always remains constant. Your command would look like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['OWNER', 'creator', 'CREATOR'])
async def owner(ctx):
    try:
        user = await client.fetch_user(YOUR_ID)
        await ctx.send(f'Owner: {user.mention}')
    except:
        user = 'MyUsername#0000'
        await ctx.send(f'Owner: **{user}**')
```

Where `YOUR_ID` is your Discord User ID that can be obtained by right-clicking your profile picture from one of your messages on Discord.

**Note:** You will only be mentioned if you are present in that server, otherwise you'll have to tell it what to send (`MyUsername#0000` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that but the important thing to note is that you (Owner of bot) must be present in server in which the command is used to actually get proper mention. Otherwise, It will show something like this:
`<@1234567890>` (Where 1234567890 is your ID).
You can use this code but again it will only mention you if you are in the server.

```py
@client.command()
async def owner(ctx):
    owner = client.get_user(Your ID)
    await ctx.send(f"Bot's Owner is {owner.mention}")
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** You need to have "Members Intents" enabled in order to get the above code running. Please enable them [Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) from your applications bot section after that enable intents in your code. Learn more from [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

This method isn't recommended since it uses intents and doesn't actually mentions the user.